# Only AMP pages or non-AMP pages + AMP pages

Tags: mobile, amp-html

Currently, we are trying to implement AMP to our current website. Non-AMP version is already ready and works as it supposed to be. Question is: 'which one would be better: to change all current pages to AMP or creating additional AMP pages and put canonical link to original pages?'

Comment: This depends on what's easier for you, and what makes sense in your situation. Do you use a lot of custom JavaScript on your site? If so it might not make sense to make the entire page AMP. If the answer is no then exploring the option of making the entire site AMP compliant may be appealing for future maintenance. This is ultimately something you need to ask yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  no doubt that AMP is fast, beautiful and high-performing across devices and distribution platforms. It can run on desktop and mobile both. But AMP is basically for mobile. I think that we should run separate for desktop (non-amp) and mobile (amp).

> In general we support the latest two versions of major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari, Opera and UC Browser. We support desktop, phone, tablet and the web view version of these respective browsers.
>
> Beyond that, the core AMP library and built-in elements should aim for very wide browser support and we accept fixes for all browsers with market share greater than 1 percent.
>
> In particular, we try to maintain "it might not be perfect but isn't broken"-support for the Android 4.0 system browser and Chrome 28+ on phones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response